# Как мне сделать увеличение одной оси при наведении на график?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть график, который я построил используя библиотеку apexchart.
Мне нужно как-то сделать увеличение масштаба при наведении на график. Я нашел в этой библиотеке параметр       **autoScaleYaxis: true** который должен это делать. После установки этого параметра ничего не происходит. Подскажите, правильно ли я использую эту настройку ? Вот ссылка на именно эту опцию в библиотеке [Ссылка на библиотеку](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/brush/)

Я пытаюсь это сделать вот так:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="chart">
      <h2 class="text-lg text-center font-semibold" v-if="title">
        {{ title }}
      </h2>

      <apexchart
        type="line"
        height="350"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :series="series"
        ref="chart"
      ></apexchart>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
export default {
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
  },
  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      series: [],
      chartOptions: {
        xaxis: {
          type: "numeric",
          labels: {
            rotate: 0,
          },
        },
        colors: ["#a4a82c", "#c416b9"],
        /*         theme: {
          palette: "palette7",
        }, */
        tickAmount: "dataPoints",
        grid: {
          show: true,
          borderColor: "#2a2c3d",
          strokeDashArray: 0,

          fill: {
            type: "gradient",
          },
          position: "back",

          chart: {
            brush: {
              autoScaleYaxis: true,
            },
          },

          xaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true,
            },
          },
          yaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true,
            },
          },
          row: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
          column: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
          padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 10,
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },

  watch: {
    title(val) {
      console.log("val", val);
    },

    dataset: {
      handler: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("newValue-dataset", newValue);
        console.log("oldValue", oldValue);
        if (newValue && newValue["x"]) {
          let series = [
            {
              name: "First Y Data 1 - portfolio pnl",

              data: this.dataset["y_portf"].map((item, index) => {
                return {
                  x: this.dataset["x"][index],
                  y: item.toFixed(2),
                };
              }),
            },
            {
              name: "First Y Data 2 - structure pnl",
              data: this.dataset["y_struct"].map((item, index) => {
                return {
                  x: this.dataset["x"][index],
                  y: item.toFixed(2),
                };
              }),
            },
          ];

          this.series = series;
        }
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.chart.hideSeries("First Y Data 1 - portfolio pnl");
      console.log("this.$refs.chart", this.$refs.chart);
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Comment: Похоже что неправильно, т.к. `brush` относится [к такому вот использованию](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/brush-chart/). Вероятно, тебе нужен параметр [yaxis.min](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/yaxis/#min) (см. описание передачи функции в качестве значения параметра).

Comment: А, **при наведении** надо (сорри, я невнимательно прочел)... тогда не `yaxis.min`, а скорее подойдет [`zoom`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/zoom/) с `zoom.autoScaleYaxis: true`. Но вот неизвестно, как там дела с реактивностью свойства `zoom.enabled`...

Comment: Нет, я уже пробовал такую настройку.. Ничего не выходи(